# Accessing unclamped values from floating point textures in WebGL fragment shader

Tags: shader, webgl, fragment-shader

I'm trying to render a matrix of luminance values on a canvas as an image, when the luminance values are between 0 and 4000. I'm using a 2D floating point texture to do so, because I had heard that they offer ranges between [-inf, inf].

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, ct.columns, ct.rows, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, gl.FLOAT, new Float32Array(ct.grid[i]));
```

However, when I go and retrieve the texture values in my fragment shader, they are always clamped between [0, 1.0]. Specifically,

```
vec4 texcolour = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
```

texcolour.rgb will always be between 0 and 1.0. How can I access unclamped values inside my fragment shader, so that I may do the normalizing myself?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you testing this?  Can you try something like

```
vec4 texcolour = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
gl_FragColor = texcolour.x > 3000.0 ? vec4(0,1,0,1) : vec4(1,0,0,1);
```

Comment: I was testing it by seeing that my entire image was white (because I do my own filtering based on windowing and level values), but after running your code I get a pure red block.

Comment: Oh and I forgot to add that when I normalize my matrix of values between 0 and 1 before creating my textures, then I see the image perfectly, which is why I concluded that it was a clamping problem and not some unrelated webGL problem.

Comment: Here's a working sample http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/LMbhk/  I'm putting in values from 0 to 256000 and then dividing by 256000 in the shader and getting what I expect. Maybe you can modify it to make it fail?

Comment: In your example, you use gl.RGBA whereas I use gl.LUMINANCE, I've convinced myself that this is what's causing the problem (there's still a chance it might not be). For some reason luminance values seem to get clamped even with gl.float. One test I could do is use rgba instead and only use one channel in the shader, but I have ~200 512x512 images so the memory usage would go up quite a bit. I'm going to try it as soon as I have time though, just to confirm.

Comment: In the meantime, I've modified your example to use gl.LUMINANCE and to show that values get clamped, I divided the red channel by 256000.0 in the shader, and put the other channels at 1.0. Since I initialized all my pixels at 256000, I am expecting a white image if the texture values are unclamped. However, I get a cyan image. http://jsfiddle.net/marc_andre/LMbhk/19/

Comment: This one works fine for me (http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/ZnqkJ/1/). Yours does exactly what you're telling it to do. You're putting 256000 and dividing but 256000 which gives you 1.0 across the entire texture. I get white.

Comment: Interesting, for your last example I get a black rectangle, and for mine I definitely get a cyan rectangle. Here's a link to screenshots of the jsfiddle screen for me, for both examples: http://imgur.com/a/Yu5Bv I'm using chrome 17.0.963.66 on Ubuntu 12.04 (although the issue was still there on ubuntu 11.10), with nVidia drivers 295.20

Comment: I just tried in Firefox and got the "correct" behaviour: http://imgur.com/a/wyWA4, could this be a bug related to Chrome?

Comment: It's a bug: (http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118091) I'm not sure why it seemed to work for me sometimes though